# How to edit data from a form in a sheet to another form with the Data using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

ive been learning VBA and Excel in the past 2 weeks by my own during my free time, but sometimes we need some help, and currently ive no one to help besides the internet. So ive developed a Form(Sheet1) in a sheet using shapes and excel cells so the user could perform operations like insert,update, new register to the other sheet(Data) which is my Data Sheet or DataTable more specifically. But im struggling to get the update button to work. i could definitely use some help.

Heres my code:

Public Upda As String

```
Sub Search()
    '
    ' Search Macro
    '
    Dim Sheet As String, ans


    On Error GoTo Erro:

    Data.Activate


    Sheet = Data.Name

    ans = InputBox("Write down the ID", "Search")

    If ans = "" Then
    Sheet1.Activate
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim C
    With Worksheets(Data).Range("A:A")

    Set C = .Find(ans, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not C Is Nothing Then

     C.Activate
     Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Value = C.Value ' Id
     Sheet1.Cells(9, 4).Value = C.Offset(0, 1).Value ' Name
     ' here goes the other fields to be inserted
     Sheet1.Activate

     Upda = Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Text
    Else

    Sheet1.Activate
    MsgBox "Insert a valid ID", vbCritical, "Search"


    End If

    End With

    Exit Sub
Erro:
        MsgBox "Something went wrong, contact the Adm!", vbCritical, "Erro"
  
End Sub

   
'Update macro need to get a fix
Sub Update()

'update macro

Dim Sheet As String


On Error GoTo Erro
If IsEmpty(Range("I17")) Or IsEmpty(Range("D9"))  Then ' there are more fields to validate
  MsgBox "All the fields must have a value", vbExclamation, "Upda"

If Upda = "" Then

 MsgBox "Please retry the search", vbExclamation, "Update"
Exit Sub
End If
Dim C
'
Data.Activate

Sheet = Data.Name

With Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A:A")

    Set C = .Find(Upda, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not C Is Nothing Then

    C.Activate

    ActiveCell.Value = Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Text ' ID
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(9, 4).Text   ' Name
  'Update the table with the contents of the form1
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    Range("I6:J6").ClearContents
         ' remaining code to clear the contents of the form sheet1
    Upda = ""

    'Call clear
Else
MsgBox "ID number not found", vcCritical, "Update"

End If
End With


Exit Sub
Erro:
MsgBox "Something went wrong, contact the Adm!", vbCritical, "ERRO"
End Sub

Sub clear()
'
' clear Macro
'
    Range("I17").ClearContents
    ' remaining code to cleear the contents of the form sheet1
    Upda = ""
End Sub
```

Each one of those macros are associated with a Button(Shape), evrything is working besides the Update one.

Im getting the follow error which makes no sense to me

[image]

**PS:if u need more information please let me know**

Comment: You have two `Ifs` at the start of the sub but only one `End If` probably want that in before the second `If`

Comment: such a rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the End if statement for the first If in the below block of code:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("I17")) Or IsEmpty(Range("D9"))  Then ' there are more fields to validate
  MsgBox "All the fields must have a value", vbExclamation, "Upda"
End if 'Missing If in the original code

If Upda = "" Then

 MsgBox "Please retry the search", vbExclamation, "Update"
Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: damn i cant believe i didnt saw that :sad:. Even though when i click the Update button it leads me to `MsgBox "ID number not found", vbCritical, "Update" '` .any tip would be very appreciated. i think im missing something else

Comment: This means the code is not finding Upda value in Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A:A"). You can try searching for it manually to insure the value is present. Also, keep in mid that your search function is set to look for the whole values, including spaces etc.
Set C = .Find(Upda, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

Comment: The main issue is that. The value is Present which im also Validating with my Search Sub, its also saving the value(ID) according to the Debug.Print( i could post it here if its necessary) after `Upda = Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Text ` But it still returning the message when i click the Update button

Comment: Its saying the Id wasnt found even though the id is there, its just weird it works with the Search but not with the Update

Comment: By the end the solution was changing the     `Upda = Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Text`  to     `Upda = Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Value` not sure why though but ill accept ur answer as a solution =), thank you for ur time

Comment: Glad that you figured. In general I nevere use .Text property. Value is the way to go. You might also inclose Trim(Sheet1. Cells(17,9).Value) , this will cover the scenarios when someone inputs a space before or after the searched string.